# Wordpress Multisite prevent direct access to subdomain

Tags: multisite, user-access

Hi I have create a multisite in Wordpress and I use the main domain for the central website that projects 13 eCommerce stores with subdomains.

I want my client/visitor to connect to the subdomain through main domain.
I do not want to be connected directly to the subdomain
If tries to connect directly I want to redirected to main domain.

Any help with that? Thanks.

Comment: So what is your problem?